# Linking HoloViews plots with Bokeh customizations

Tags: bokeh, holoviews

I'm struggling with some of the finer points of complex HoloViews plots, especially linked plots customizing the appearance of fonts and data points.

Using the following code, I can create [this plot](http://aldaron.com/junk/testHV.html) that has most of the features I want, but am stumped by a few things:

- I want one marginal for the whole set of plots linked to `'ewr'` (with individual marginals for each of the other axes), ideally on the left of the set; but my attempts to get just one in my definitions of `s1` and `s2` haven't worked, and I can find nothing in the documentation about moving a marginal to the left (or bottom for that matter).
- I want to be able to define tooltips that use columns from my data that are not displayed in the plots. I can see one way of accomplishing this as shown in the commented alternate definition for `s1`, but that unlinks the plot it creates from the others. How do I create linked plots that have tooltips with elements not in those plots?

For reference, the data used is available [here](https://www.kaggle.com/luniki/is-there-a-good-performance-metric-for-keyforge/data) (converted in the code below to a Pandas dataframe, `df`).

---

```py
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import dim, opts

hv.extension('bokeh')

renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh') 
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from holoviews.plotting.links import DataLink

TOOLS="crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,zoom_in,zoom_out,box_zoom,undo,redo,reset,tap,save,box_select,poly_select,lasso_select".split(",") 
ht = HoverTool(
        tooltips=[('Name', '@{name}'), ('EWR', '@{ewr}{%0.2f}'), ('Win Rate', '@{winrate}{%d}')],
        formatters={'ewr' : 'printf', 'winrate' : 'printf'})

point_opts = opts.Scatter(fill_color='black', fill_alpha=0.1, line_width=1, line_color='gray', size=5, tools=TOOLS+[ht])
hist_opts = opts.Histogram(fill_color='gray', fill_alpha=0.9, line_width=1, line_color='gray', tools=['box_select'], labelled=[None, None])

#s1 = hv.Scatter(df[['kfai','ewr','name','winrate']]).hist(num_bins=51, dimension='kfai')
s1 = hv.Scatter(df, 'kfai','ewr').hist(num_bins=51, dimension='kfai')
s2 = hv.Scatter(df, 'aerc', 'ewr').hist(num_bins=51, dimension=['aerc',None])
s3 = hv.Scatter(df, 'winrate', 'ewr').hist(num_bins=51, dimension=['winrate','ewr'])
p = (s1 + s2 + s3).opts(point_opts, hist_opts, opts.Layout(shared_axes=True, shared_datasource=True))

renderer.save(p, '_testHV')
```